# How to obtain a vector perpendicular to a set of vectors (with Matlab)?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, orthogonal

Let suppose I want to build a set of N orthonormal vectors. 
Actually I know N-1 orthonormal vectors and I just want to learn the last one.

I should to solve a linear system, setting to zero each scalar product between the N-1 known vectors and that one to find. But how could I do that with Matlab?

EDIT: note that this problem can be seen as a system of linear equations.
If *U* is the *(N-1xN)* matrix whose rows contain the known vectors, then I should solve the equation *Ux = 0*, with *x* the vector to find and *0* the vector of zeros.
To do that I used this simple code:

```
   x = U\0
```

But, in this way, it obviously returns the banal solution *0*. I need to the non trivial solution, any idea?

Comment: Do what? Solve a system of linear equations? ` \ ` <- this dude will do it

Comment: I don't think. It returns the banal solution vector 0

Comment: Yeah, what about showing us the code? Please, read [ask] and especially [mcve]

Comment: I read this, but in this case I don't think I have to post my code. I would only know if there is a smart way to find a vector orthonormal to other ones

Comment: Unfortunately I think you do.  there is too many people that refuses to ask to people asking "plz do this for me". I don't know if you are asking that or a honest question unless you show some effort, i.e. a MCVE

Comment: It was a specific question in order to understand if there exist a function able to compute a specific work.
Really, I don't know how to enhace my question.

Comment: Just showing what you tried really. You mention it gives solution 0 so you must have tried it. Just CTRL+C CTRL+V that code. Again, this is not against you, its just we receive about 30 questions every day that say "plz no idea how to do things plz give me codez". Just giving you advice to avoid being mistaked by someone like that

Comment: @AnderBiguri Ok, I understand it. I edited my question, thank you for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm quite sure you want a non-trivial solution to a linear system that satisfies `Ax = 0` without `x` being a vector of zeros.

This can be done using [Singular value decomposition](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/svd.html) like this:

```
A = [2 -1 1; 2 -1 1; 3 2 1];
[U S V] = svd(A);
x = V(:,end)

x =

  -0.39057
   0.13019
   0.91132

A*x = 

   0
   0
   0
```